# Issue trying to set the PieChart Legend vertical in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, layout

I've created my custom PieChart class to make my own Legend, in my program the pieChart as to be updated runtime and so as the Legend too, I know my code isn't well designed and I've used bad to solution to gain what I want but it works, and it's a private project so it don't need to be perfect.
Anyway this is my code:

```
public class CustomPieChart extends PieChart {
    public ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    public Legend theLegend;
     public CustomPieChart(ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data){
        super(data);
        setTitle("MyTitle");
        setLegendSide(Side.RIGHT);
        setLabelsVisible(false);
        ((Legend)getLegend()).setVertical(true);
        ((Legend)getLegend()).setPrefColumns(1);
     }

    private void createScrollableLegend(){
        setStartAngle(180); 
        setLabelLineLength(20);
        if(getLegend()!= null){
            theLegend=(Legend) getLegend();
            theLegend.setPrefWidth(130);


            scrollPane.setContent(theLegend);
            scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
            scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
            scrollPane.maxHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
            setLegend(scrollPane);  

        }
    }
    public void refreshChart(ObservableList<PieChart.Data> data){
        if(getData()!=null){
            getData().clear();
        }

        //This is the only way I found to "refresh" the values of the legend
        CustomPieChart tmp = new CustomPieChart(data);
        setLegend((Legend)tmp.getLegend());

        setData(data);
        createScrollableLegend();

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a scrollable Legend that goes vertical only instead this is what I got
:

[image: screenshot of UI]

As you can see some of the element are displayed outside the Pane...

Be gentle I'm pretty noob ^^